# Input number A and B and sum them together, given that A has a pre-defined limit in Python

Tags: python

I am doing a calculator that input number A and number B then sum them up, given that A has a pre-defined limit (e.g. A has to be less than 8)

```
def welcome():
    print("Welcome user")
    print("")

def ans_num1():
    num1 = int(input("Enter your 1st num: "))
    while num1 <= limit1:
        print("Good boy")
        break
    else:
        print("Wrong input")
        ans_num1()

def ans_num2():
    num2 = input("Enter your 2st num: ")


def calculator():   
    print("The sum of 2 numbers are: ")
    print(num1 + num2)
    print("")

def thanks():
    print("Thank you and Goodbye :)")


welcome()
limit1 = int(input("Enter your limit: "))
asknum1()
asknum2()
calculator()
thanks()
```

But I am getting an error message saying that:

`The sum of 2 numbers are:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  line 31, in <module>
    calculator()
  line 20, in calculator
    print(num1 + num2)
NameError: name 'num1' is not defined`

I am new to python and stuck, need help right now!

Comment: You need to look up how to return variables from functions... also your loop to make sure num1 is below 8 doesn't work...

Comment: You may now think about [accepting an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) or comment one to get details ;) to reward those who spent time for you ;)

Answer (score 1):

When doing the following you create a variable `num2` local to the method, it can only accessed in the method's scope, you need to return values from the method in one way and pass them as parameter in another way

```
def ans_num2():
    num2 = input("Enter your 2st num: ")
```

Giving :

```
def welcome():
    print("Welcome user\n")

def asknum(limit, nb):
    res = int(input("Enter your number %s " % nb))
    while res > limit:
        res = int(input("Enter your number %s " % nb))
    return res

def calculator(num1, num2):
    print("The sum of 2 numbers are: ", num1 + num2, "\n")

def thanks():
    print("Thank you and Goodbye :)")

welcome()
limit = int(input("Enter your limit: "))
num1 = asknum(limit, 1)
num2 = asknum(limit, 2)
calculator(num1, num2)
thanks()
```

Comment: good answer, but printing is not OK, note that print sep is whitespace by default. And all that `\n` is extra too.

Comment: @Nikscorp I don't think 1-2 space here or here matters, seeing the level of problem of the code. Also the \n replace the empty print, thanks for you concern ;)

Answer (score 0):

`num1` and `num2` are local variable i.e they dont have scope outside the function they are declared in . to fix them declare them outside the function or add global keyword.
also you have written `asknum1()` and not `ans_num1()` same with `ans_num2()`

```
def welcome():
print("Welcome user")
print("")

def ans_num1():
    global num1                                #num1 is declared globally
    num1 = int(input("Enter your 1st num: "))
    while num1 <= limit1:
        print("Good boy")
        break
    else:
        print("Wrong input")
        ans_num1()

def ans_num2():
   global num2                                 #declared globally
   num2= int(input("Enter your 2st num: "))


def calculator():
    print("The sum of 2 numbers are: ")
    print(num1 + num2)
    print("")

def thanks():
    print("Thank you and Goodbye :)")


welcome()
limit1 = int(input("Enter your limit: "))     #already declared globally
ans_num1()                                    #fixed the function name
ans_num2()
calculator()
thanks()
```